# How to perform a custom check of the arguments being passed to mockito mocks

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I have a problem writing tests for scala project using specs2 and mockito.
Is there a way to perform some complex checks for arguments that was passed by a method being tested to a mocked service method? For example:

```
  session = ....
  sessionDao.getByUid(sessionUID).returns(Some(session))

  val result = service.refreshSessionFor(token)

  result must beLeft

  got{
    one(sessionDao).getByUid(sessionUID)
    one(sessionDao).update(any[Session])
  }
```

The problem is, i want to check whether field "lastUsed" of session object was updated or not. The only way is to check parameter fields of the sessionDao.update method. But I cannot find how to do this in the mockito manual.

Comment: Can you post what your session class looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any specs2 matcher to a mocked method:

```
got{
  one(sessionDao).getByUid(sessionUID)
  one(sessionDao).update(beLike[Session] { case s: Session => s.lastUsed must be_>(last) })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking through the docs for matcher, but missed this!

Comment: NB! Be careful, it is required to add hamcrest into the dependencies!